# React: rendering content (view) according to requested route (ExpressJS)

Tags: node.js, express, view, reactjs, routes

I have recently started learning React and am trying to make a simple blogging app. I store the data (post content, comments etc.) in MongoDB and would like to render the content according to the route, such as, when I have a certain URL (like /blog/:username), I'd pull data from the database and then render a view with the data content.

Using Express, I am now using static html files ( `express.static`) as the view, yet this makes it impossible to render the content according to the requested route, such as:

```
/blog/:username/:article
```

It is possible with a template engine, like **Jade**, but Jade, as far as I know, does not work with React.

What is the correct way to make dynamic views using React while preserving the URL route structure?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, there are several ways to achieve your goal. I'll sketch the one that I feel is the most natural approach when using React:

1. Create your blogging app with React
2. Use a frontend routing mechanism such as `react-router` to make React aware of the URL
3. Either fetch the data for each blog entry from the backend via an Ajax call each time the user hits a URL, or store the blog entry data in the frontend (e.g. using something like `redux`) and reuse it when required.

Does this make sense? If not, please keep asking...